# Chess openings variations on-line

Tags: opening

I need a web site, where there are links with the names of openings and they and their variations are
illustrated graphically rather than as a chess notation like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishop%27s_Opening)

move by move.

Does this exist ?

Comment: Hello welcome to chess stack exchange. So in your question you put the tag software but this question does not relate to software could you please remove the tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As well as chess.com you might look at its free cousin Lichess

https://lichess.org/analysis#explorer

I've also recently come across

http://www.chesstree.net/

which may be of interest

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. But why downvote ?

Answer (score 3):

Chess.com is a great website to train and learn openings. I believe that the answer to your question is this website: https://www.chess.com/openings/

Answer (score 3):

[image: You may find detailed images like this helpful, too. I have a few more examples on https://named-openings-galore.com/.]

You may find detailed images like this helpful, too.
I have a few more examples on https://named-openings-galore.com/.